# scheduling Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: ubuntu, download, scheduled-tasks

Is there an easy way to schedule downloads through the 'Ubuntu Software Center'?

For example: mark a number of programs for download and installation between 2am and 8am?

Comment: See `/etc/cron.daily/apt` for details. :)

Comment: Thats a little different to what I need. I want to mark particular programs for download & instillation as opposed to performing a scheduled update.

Comment: Ah. Try adding your own shell script in `/etc/cron.daily/` that runs `apt-get install packagename`. I think it won't do anything if the package is up to date, and will install it without hassle if it isn't. Not sure about the `dpkg-reconfigure` stuff. You can have the `/etc/cron.daily/apt` file download the latest package lists for you.

Comment: k, i'll play around with it. Its unfortunate the functionality isn't built into 'Ubuntu Software Center'. Is there any easy way to customise the 'Ubuntu Software Center'to allow this? (sounds like the answer is no).

Comment: @user81182, I understand where you're coming from, but the Unix philosophy is to have a general purpose scheduling tool (`crond`) that can schedule anything to do anything with extremely flexible time specifications. :) The difficulty with your case is that you only want a subset of packages to be updated -- the configuration is very well prepared to upgrade _everything_ or _nothing_, but middle grounds require a slightly further step. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ended up using cron to call a script. The script contained a list of programs to download/install e.g. "sudo apt-get install eclipse". Thank you.

Comment: @user81182, I'm sorry I didn't ask sooner if you wanted this for a one-time package installation, or if you wanted to keep this one specific set of packages up to date overnight but wanted to keep all the others updated on your own schedule. Had I asked better questions up front, I might have been able to give better advice. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Ubuntu Software Center' doesn't specifically allow scheduling of software downloads/installation. However, the general purpose task scheduler *crontab* can be used to download/install programs. For example: to download/install eclipse at 2:30am:

1. Go to the terminal and open crontab for editing:

   ```
   sudo crontab -e
   ```
2. Add the following line:

   ```
   * 30 2 * * * apt-get install eclipse > /dev/null
   ```
3. Save and close crontab (Ctrl + W for write)

Crontab will run at 2:30am and download/install eclipse. Any terminal outputs from this activity will be sent to `/dev/null` (trashed).

Tip: this site allows you to automatically build crontab entries:

> http://www.htmlbasix.com/crontab.shtml

Answer (score 5):

You could try using an `at` command to run a scheduled `apt-get install package`.